# Prove that $\exists \delta>0$ such that $0<|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow\Big|\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(c)\Big|<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable at $c\in I$. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>, \exists \delta>0$ such that $0<|x-y|<\delta$ and $a\leq x\leq c \leq y\leq b\Rightarrow\Big|\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(c)\Big|<\varepsilon$

My attempt: $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $c\in I$, i.e. $f'(c)$ exists.

So, $0<|x-c|<\dfrac{\delta}{2} \Rightarrow\Big|\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\Big|<\varepsilon$

And $0<|y-c|<\dfrac{\delta}{2} \Rightarrow\Big|\dfrac{f(y)-f(c)}{y-c}-f'(c)\Big|<\varepsilon$

I'm stuck here. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $x<c<y.$ Then

$$\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = \frac{y-c}{y-x}\cdot\frac{f(y) - f(c)}{y-c} +\frac{c-x}{y-x}\cdot \frac{f(c) - f(x)}{c-x}.$$

Comment: $\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = \frac{y-c}{y-x}\cdot\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-c} $, right? Why is it $\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = \frac{y-c}{y-x}\cdot\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-c} +\frac{c-x}{y-x}\cdot \frac{f(c) - f(x)}{c-x}$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = \frac{y-c}{2(y-x)}\cdot\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-c} +\frac{c-x}{2(y-x)}\cdot \frac{f(c) - f(x)}{c-x}.$ then?

Comment: That should be $f(y)-f(c).$ I fixed it, thanks. I think everything else is OK.