# $\frac{x-c}{x-y} |\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} - f'(c)| + \frac{c-y}{x-y}|\frac{f(y) - f(c)}{y-c} - f'(c)| < (\frac{x-c}{x-y} + \frac{c-y}{x-y}) \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis

After substituting the green expression, how do you deduce [the last two inequalities below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3848453)? I'm guessing Triangle Inequality? But after you substitute the green expression, you have three terms, whilst Triangle Inequality has just two variables.

> Since $f(x)−f(y)=f(x)\color{red}{−f(c)+f(c)}−f(y)$, a simple
> calculation shows that
>
> $\color{green}{\dfrac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} = \dfrac{x-c}{x-y}\cdot\dfrac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} +\dfrac{c-y}{x-y}\cdot \dfrac{f(y) - f(c)}{y-c}}$
>
> Since both $\dfrac{x-c}{x-y}$ and $\dfrac{c-y}{x-y}$ are positive and sum to 1, it follows that
>
> $\begin{align} 
> & \left|\color{green}{\dfrac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}}-f'(c)\right| \\
> & \le (\frac{x-c}{x-y})\left|\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} - f'(c) \right| +(\frac{c-y}{x-y})\left|\frac{f(y) - f(c)}{y-c} - f'(c)\right|  \\
> & < (\frac{x-c}{x-y} +  \frac{c-y}{x-y})\epsilon \\
> & \qquad = \epsilon \end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $x<c<y$, we justify it by
$$1=\frac{x-y}{x-y}=\frac{x-c}{x-y}+\frac{c-y}{x-y}$$
and with the calculations (using the triangle inequality in the "$\leq$" step)
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(c)\right| &=\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-y}+\frac{f(c)-f(y)}{x-y}-\left(\frac{x-c}{x-y}+\frac{c-y}{x-y}\right)f'(c)\right|\\
&\leq\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-y}-\frac{x-c}{x-y}f'(c)\right|+\left|\frac{f(c)-f(y)}{x-y}-\frac{c-y}{x-y}f'(c)\right|\\
&=\left(\frac{x-c}{x-y}\right)\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|+\left(\frac{c-y}{x-y}\right)\left|\frac{f(c)-f(y)}{c-y}-f'(c)\right|
\end{align*}

**Addendum:**
I had missed you asking about the second inequality. Here it goes:

By the fact that $f:I=[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c\in I$, we can find, for any arbitrarily fixed $\epsilon > 0$
a $\delta:=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such for all $x\in I$ with $|x-c|<\delta$, we have $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|<\epsilon.$$

Start from the last expression above and assume $|x-c|<\delta$ and $|c-y|<\delta$. We get

$$\left(\frac{x-c}{x-y}\right)\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|+\left(\frac{c-y}{x-y}\right)\left|\frac{f(c)-f(y)}{c-y}-f'(c)\right| \\< 
\left(\frac{x-c}{x-y}\right)\epsilon + \left(\frac{c-y}{x-y}\right)\epsilon =\left(\frac{x-c}{x-y}+\frac{c-y}{x-y}\right)\epsilon = \epsilon
$$